# Registering multiple instances of the same IHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to register multiple instance of my IHostedService in asp.net core. I need it to subscribe to multiple queues and process messages in them.
Here's the extension method I implemented to register an instance of my queue subscriber:

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddQueueSubscription<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string accountName, string queueName,
        Func<IServiceProvider,Func<T, Task>> actionResolver)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(ctx =>
        {
            return new BackgroundQueueSubscriber(new QueueInfo
                {
                    Account = accountName,
                    Name = queueName,
                    Action = msg => actionResolver(ctx)(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(msg.AsString))
                },
                ctx.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(),
                ctx.GetRequiredService<IMetrics>());
        });
        return services;
    }
```

BackgroundQueueSubscriber implements IHostedService.

Despite registering multiple instance I get a runtime error which says "Unable to resolve service for type QueueInfo while attempting to activate BackgroundQueueSubscriber".
Why is it trying to create an instance disregarding the implementation code I supplied, shown above?

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I solved the problem. The problem was, that I used Scrutor nuget to register in DI every class in my assembly as implemented interface, so it picked up BackgroundQueueSubscriber as implementation of IHostedService. As a result it tried to instantiate it, and it caused the exception to be thrown. The solution was to add a filter to Scrutor not to automatically register this class.

Comment: Do you inject `BackgroundQueueSubscriber` into another class? If so try `services.AddSingleton<BackgroundQueueSubscriber>`

Comment: I do not inject it into another class, it's supposed to be picked up by `WebHost` in asp.net core.

Comment: Have you tried adding it via `services.AddHostedService`? See [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: try it ..services.AddHostedService<BackgroundQueueSubscriber>();
services.AddHostedService<QueueInfo>();

Comment: I cannot register an instance using `AddHostedService`. I want to register specific instances.